# Я не могу написать код на java, ошибка java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect

Tags: java, javax

Есть такой класс, с помощью которого моё приложение должно отправлять сообщение с одного email1@yandex.ru на другой email2@yandex.ru, соответственно я заменил настоящий пароль и адрес
но при выполнении кода получаю ошибку

```
Exception in thread "main" com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: imap.yandex.ru, 465; timeout -1;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:2209)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:740)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:388)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:246)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:195)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:254)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
    at Main.main(Main.java:38)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:576)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:565)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:588)
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:333)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:645)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:595)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:359)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:238)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:2175)
    ... 7 more
```

Вот сам код

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.AddressException;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

public class Main {
    private static String password = "mypswrd";
    private static  String user = "email1@yandex.ru";
    private static String host = "imap.yandex.ru";
    public static void main(String[] args) throws MessagingException {
        String to = "email2@yandex.ru";
        String hostSMTP = "smtp.yandex.ru";
        Integer port = 465;

        Properties prop = new Properties();
        prop.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
        prop.put("mail.smtp.ssl.enable", "true");
        prop.put("mail.smtp.port", port);
        prop.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(prop, new Authenticator() {
            @Override
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(user, password);

            }
        });
        Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
        msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(user));
        InternetAddress[] addresses = {new InternetAddress(to) };
        msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, addresses);
        msg.setSubject("Email from java");
        msg.setSentDate(new Date());
        msg.setText("Пример Пример ");

        Transport.send(msg);


    }


}
```

как решить проблему?

Я пробовал так же делать с помощью gmail, но не получилось, такая же проблема.
с интернетом всё в порядке,
на почте настроил доступ по imap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам надо поставить пароль не от почты, а сгенерировать пароль для сторонних приложений. Потому что и яндекс и гугл не примут ваш пароль от почты не через их приложение - подробнее - [support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833)

Попробовал ваш код на своей почте - код рабочий, дело только в пароле.